# CSS3 Animations not responding

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to implement a simple slide-in slide-out animation for a menu prototype using only CSS.

Code: https://jsbin.com/lelizi/171/edit?html,css,output

I am able to play the animation when I click the link using :target to trigger it. The problem is that when I click the transparent anchor div to go back to the main-slide the animation is not triggered and it goes back instantly to the main-slide.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS rules are setup on different elements. So when you target the `main-slide` you're setting an animation on that element, not the `left-slide` element. Aside from that your `left-slide` element is full-width so you will likely target a child-element of the `left-slide` element when you try to click off it it, rather than targeting the `main-slide` element.

Since your animation is so simple, might I suggest using a transition instead?

Demo using a transition: https://jsfiddle.net/zuksntxb/

```
#left-slide {
    transition : transform 400ms ease-in;
}

#left-slide:target {
    transform : translateX(100%);
}
```

EDIT (Bonus Round):

You can set CSS on an element other than the one being targeted, but it has to be a subsequent sibling (or a descendant of a subsequent sibling):

```
#main-slide:target ~ #left-slide {
   /*DO SOMETHING TO #left-slide*/
}
```

This requires the order of the HTML of your slides to be switched. It also doesn't really work with how your left-slide totally covers the main-slide.